# Thread pool with ServletContextListener

Tags: java, multithreading

I want to run some simple background process calculations but I can't seem to figure it out. No matter what I do, it blocks.

```
public class WorkThreadManagerContextLoaderListener implements ServletContextListener {
    private Runnable runnable;
    private WorkManager workManager;

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {
        final WebApplicationContext springContext = WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(event.getServletContext());
        workManager = (WorkManager) springContext.getBean("workThreadManager");

        runnable = new WorkThreadManagerStartUp(WorkManager);

        runnable.run();
    }

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent event) {
        workManager.shutDown();
    }
}
```

The reason why WorkThreadManagerStartUp exist is because I don't want it to block so I made it a Runnable type and when run() is called, it starts up an ExecutorService:

```
public class UnitOfWorkThreadManagerStartUp implements Runnable {
    private WorkManager workManager;

    public UnitOfWorkThreadManagerStartUp(WorkManager workManager) {
        this.workManager = workManager;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        workManager.startUp();
    }
}

public class WorkThreadManager implements WorkManager {
    @Autowired
    private WorkService workService;

    private final int availableProcessors = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
    private final ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4 * availableProcessors);

    @Override
    public void startUp() {
        // this method always blocks...
    }
}
```

But my solution doesn't work as expected. I'm running on Tomcat 7.0.30.

What I'm trying to figure out is how I can start a thread pool in the background without stopping the web app from deploying because currently it can never fully come online due to startUp() always blocking. I'd like to simplify this solution and possibly removing WorkThreadManagerStartUp class if it's not really needed.

EDIT:

I modified the start up class

```
public class WorkThreadManagerStartUp implements Runnable {
    private WorkManager workManager;

    public WorkThreadManagerStartUp(WorkManager workManager) {
        this.workManager = workManager;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
    try {
        while (true) {
                System.out.println("Hello World!");
                Thread.sleep(1000 * 10);
            }
        } catch(InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Although this is suppose to run on it's own thread, Hello World! displays multiple times as expected but does not allow the web app to come online.

Comment: Usually you put the stuffs that need to be done in the run method of your Runnable and let a Thread call that method implicitly, but you are invoking it yourself. It's not quite clear what you are trying to do. What's in the method that you are saying is blocking?

Comment: From the ServletContextListener I'm instantiating WorkThreadManagerStartUp. When I call the run method, I'd like it to continue doing it's work in the background without interrupting the start up of the web app.

Comment: Then instead of `runnable.run();`, you should do `new Thread(runnable).start();`. That way it will run in a new separate thread.

Comment: Yep. Noob mistake. I did. I should have called start instead of run. I understand now what you meant by "invoking it yourself".

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your source, I don't see any threads actually being created.  Typically you do something like the following to fork a thread:

```
new Thread(new WorkThread(...)).start();
```

This will call the `WorkThread.run()` method in the new thread.  If you are using an `ExecutorService` (usually recommended over "by hand" code that uses `Thread`) then you would do:

```
executorService.submit(new WorkThread(...));
...
// when done with the service you have to shut it down
executorService.shutdown();
```

If you are injecting your `WorkManager` class into your listener class then I would just add a `submit(...)` method on the manager and in the listener do something like:

```
workManager.submit(new WorkThread());
```

This would mean that the `WorkThreadManagerStartUp` class is just not necessary.  You submit your worker thread or unit of work to the service.

In terms of Spring, I'd just make your `WorkManager` class implement `InitializingBean` and `DisposableBean` so it can start and stop its service itself.  No reason to have another bean do that.  Then you can inject the manager into any class that wants to run a `WorkThread` using the `ExecutorService` managed by the manager.

Comment: I agree you should use the executor service as a general good practice. You might also need a way to monitor the runnable/callable task you submit and maybe have it return a result using a future. By the way, I don't have experience with web servers, but isn't it bad practice to manage your own thread in a web server? Isn't there a way to have the server do that for you?